# javascript - removing an array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'll pseudocode this to begin:

```
array = copper, oil, silver, bronze, gold, iron

user inputs the letter 'l'

if (the input has the letter 'l', remove everything from the array except words with 'l') {

output = copper, bronze, iron
```

my code:

```
//arr = iron, oil, gold, silver, bronze

classDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("searchOutputName");

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

   market = arr[i];

   var n = market.indexOf(userInput.value);

      if (n >= 0) {
      classDiv[i].appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));

}
else {
      //do nothing
}
```

I have 5 div boxs for my search function.

If the user inputs 'l' the first box is empty, then it says oil, gold, silver, then another empty box. I want to make it so they stack up... first box has oil, then gold, then silver then 2 empty boxs.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you looking to remove an array element or limit the DOM nodes that you create? Also, can you create a JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem that you're seeing, because the code that you provided would not do what you've describe.

Comment: Why not use jquery autocomplete? Should do what you need unless you can't use jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also could use filter for the javascript:

```
var arr = ["copper", "oil", "silver", "bronze", "gold", "iron"];
arr = arr.filter(function(item){ return item.indexOf('l')>=0;});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not added html to your code, I have managed to do it with JS which can be reworked to fit your need.

```
var arr = ["copper", "oil", "silver", "bronze", "gold", "iron"];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].indexOf('l') !== -1) {
        arr.splice(i, 1); // Remove the element from array
        i = i - 1;  // Equalize to manage the removed array length
    }
}
console.log(arr);  //returns ["copper", "bronze", "iron"]
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jn4Fw/1/) (Based on the pseudocode you have posted)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want to sort the array by the elements that match the user input. How about something like this?

```
var text = 'l', t = ['iron', 'oil', 'gold', 'silver', 'bronze']
t.sort(function(a, b) { return a.indexOf(text) < b.indexOf(text) })
// => ["oil", "gold", "silver", "iron", "bronze"]
```

Comment: You should again need to take a look at the pseudocode of OP's.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you should use. It works, contrary to the other answer which has a bug.

```
function filter(items, criteria)
{
  var i, result;

  result = [];
  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
  {
    if (items[i].indexOf('l') !== -1)
    {
        result.push(items[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

You can filter by the criteria this way:

```
// market  = [ 'copper', 'oil', 'silver', 'bronze', 'gold', 'iron' ];
// userInput = '1';

subset = filter(market, userInput);
```

Comment: Why you have to write the filter yourself? You have it already in JS.

Comment: Oh really? I can't recall it, what are you referring to?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: I see. That's ES5 while full cross-browser compatibility (esp. older browsers like IE6) require a polyfill.